# Why does a USB cable allow MTP (Media Transfer Protocol ) but not mass storage device?

Tags: usb, adapter

So I purchased a small Micro USB right angle adapter from eBay, one end is male micro USB B and the other end is the same but female, and at a 90 degree angle.

I originally intended to simply apply heat and bend it into a U shape. Why is because I am going to be attaching some hardware to the back of my tablet. I want to be cable to put my tablet into my bag without the cable being bent into a U shape, and I can have a sideways 90 degree (as it is now) because there is a headphone port on one side and the corner of the tablet on the other.

So I removed the rubber molded cover and inside are some wires embedded in dried hot glue.

I count three but I am uncertain. So I tested it, I plugged the male end into the tablet and did the following

Plugged a charger in for the tablet, it charges, so power pins are good.
Plugged a USB cable in and with a USB flash drive. Nothing happens, no light on USB and nothing in device manager.

So next I plugged this little adapter I got into my phone, it charges, cool. Next I plugged it into my PC, (the Android OnePlus One is in MTP mode). And boom it works, I made a file, disconnected and the file was on the phone visible in the file manager.

So what’s going on, all I need is a U shaped extension. Will it be okay to remove the glue and simply wire each pin to the same pin on the other connector like pin-1 male to pin-1 female. I will reglue or superglue it to keep it together.

But how come mass storage does not work but Media Transfer Protocol (MTP) does?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If it does not pass through pin 4, the ID pin, then it is not [OTG (On The Go)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go) compatible. It’s a regular USB extension, for USB micro B slaves. You need on that is OTG compatible for it to work for OTG devices like connecting a USB flash drive to the tablet.

Comment: okay thank you, I will remove the glue and wire each pin to its corresponding one thanks :)